# SQL query performance REQUIRES use of IS NULL condition (in JAVA)

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I've a query that has a quite strange behavior (I cannot show it all, it's quite long and with various joins). 
Inside the query I've a test over a value (a number) like this:

```
       AND (
        R.CAPACITY IS NULL
        OR
        R.CAPACITY = 0
        OR
        (R.CAPACITY BETWEEN :minSeats AND :maxSeats)
       )
```

It works without any problem. It is fast, when I ran it directly from IDE (I use IDEA) as when I run it from code (tests or triggering it from the interface).

What I don't understand is that, if the first two conditions

```
        R.CAPACITY IS NULL
        OR
        R.CAPACITY = 0
```

are removed the query becomes extremely slow. Not everywhere, because in IDEA it is still quite fast. But, from code it's impossible to use it.

I've tried to change the data on the database, to create (changing the data) indexes, to change the WHERE condition with a JOIN where the data is filtered by this conditions. No way. Nothing works. It's always really fast (as expected, by the way) in IDEA but slow, too much slow, in code. I run it against an Oracle DB (version 9).

Strange is also that the field has no NULL values, but to be fast the query requires a check against them.

Has anyone idea why this happens?

EDIT (sorry, I've switched the plans)

Explain plan of FAST query is:

```
Plan hash value: 3802388129
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                     |     7 |  1463 |  1887   (8)| 00:00:23 |
|   1 |  SORT UNIQUE                      |                     |     7 |  1463 |  1886   (8)| 00:00:23 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                     |     7 |  1463 |  1885   (8)| 00:00:23 |
|   3 |    VIEW                           |                     |     7 |  1288 |   754  (10)| 00:00:10 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                     |                     |     7 |  2891 |   754  (10)| 00:00:10 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN OUTER              |                     |     7 |  2688 |   750  (10)| 00:00:10 |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                |                     |     7 |   476 |   750  (10)| 00:00:09 |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS               |                     |     7 |   147 |   743  (10)| 00:00:09 |
|*  8 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | DATUM_U1            |     1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |         VIEW                      | VW_NSO_1            |     7 |    91 |   742  (10)| 00:00:09 |
|* 10 |          FILTER                   |                     |       |       |            |          |
|  11 |           SORT GROUP BY           |                     |     7 |   189 |   742  (10)| 00:00:09 |
|  12 |            MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN   |                     |  1170K|    30M|   679   (2)| 00:00:09 |
|  13 |             MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN  |                     |  2808 | 53352 |    54   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL    | TABLEA              |   108 |  1728 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |              BUFFER SORT          |                     |    26 |    78 |    25   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |               INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| SYS_C0012272        |    26 |    78 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |             BUFFER SORT           |                     |   417 |  3336 |   742  (10)| 00:00:09 |
|  18 |              INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | SYS_C0012270        |   417 |  3336 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLEA              |     1 |    47 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0012267        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |       VIEW                        |                     |     1 |   316 |     5 (100)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |        FILTER                     |                     |       |       |            |          |
|  23 |         MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN      |                     |   595 |    98K|    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |          VIEW                     | index$_join$_006    |     5 |   445 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 25 |           HASH JOIN               |                     |       |       |            |          |
|  26 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | TABLEB              |     5 |   445 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  27 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | TABLEC              |     5 |   445 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  28 |          BUFFER SORT              |                     |   119 |  9520 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  29 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL       | TABLED              |   119 |  9520 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL            | TABLEE              |    28 |   812 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  31 |    VIEW                           |                     |  1636 | 40900 |  1130   (7)| 00:00:14 |
|* 32 |     FILTER                        |                     |       |       |            |          |
|* 33 |      HASH JOIN                    |                     |  3845K|   245M|  1130   (7)| 00:00:14 |
|* 34 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL           | TABLEF              |   106 |  1378 |    12   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|  35 |       NESTED LOOPS                |                     |   290K|    14M|  1096   (5)| 00:00:14 |
|* 36 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLEG              |   290K|    13M|  1064   (2)| 00:00:13 |
|* 37 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_TABLEH           |     1 |     5 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 38 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | TABLEG              |     1 |    36 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 39 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN            | TABLEI              |     3 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 40 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TABLEG              |     1 |    36 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 41 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN           | TABLEI              |     3 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 42 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLEL              |     1 |    23 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Plan of SLOW query:

```
Plan hash value: 453029505

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                     |     2 |   434 |  1348   (7)| 00:00:17 |
|   1 |  SORT UNIQUE                      |                     |     2 |   434 |  1347   (7)| 00:00:17 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                     |     2 |   434 |  1346   (7)| 00:00:17 |
|   3 |    VIEW                           |                     |     2 |   384 |   215   (9)| 00:00:03 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                  |                     |     2 |   826 |   215   (9)| 00:00:03 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN OUTER              |                     |     2 |   768 |   213   (9)| 00:00:03 |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                |                     |     2 |   136 |   212   (9)| 00:00:03 |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS               |                     |     2 |    42 |   210   (9)| 00:00:03 |
|*  8 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | DATUM_U1            |     1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |         VIEW                      | VW_NSO_1            |     2 |    26 |   209   (9)| 00:00:03 |
|* 10 |          FILTER                   |                     |       |       |            |          |
|  11 |           SORT GROUP BY           |                     |     2 |    58 |   209   (9)| 00:00:03 |
|  12 |            MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN   |                     |   291K|  8252K|   194   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|  13 |             MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN  |                     |   699 | 14679 |    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL    | TABLEA              |    27 |   486 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |              BUFFER SORT          |                     |    26 |    78 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |               INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| SYS_C0012272        |    26 |    78 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |             BUFFER SORT           |                     |   417 |  3336 |   209   (9)| 00:00:03 |
|  18 |              INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | SYS_C0012270        |   417 |  3336 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLEA              |     1 |    47 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0012267        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |       VIEW                        |                     |     1 |   316 |     5 (100)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |        FILTER                     |                     |       |       |            |          |
|  23 |         MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN      |                     |   595 |    98K|    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |          VIEW                     | index$_join$_006    |     5 |   445 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 25 |           HASH JOIN               |                     |       |       |            |          |
|  26 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | TABLEB              |     5 |   445 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  27 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | TABLEC              |     5 |   445 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  28 |          BUFFER SORT              |                     |   119 |  9520 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  29 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL       | TABLED              |   119 |  9520 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | TABLEE              |     1 |    29 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | SYS_C0012290        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |    VIEW                           |                     |  1636 | 40900 |  1130   (7)| 00:00:14 |
|* 33 |     FILTER                        |                     |       |       |            |          |
|* 34 |      HASH JOIN                    |                     |  3845K|   245M|  1130   (7)| 00:00:14 |
|* 35 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL           | TABLEF              |   106 |  1378 |    12   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|  36 |       NESTED LOOPS                |                     |   290K|    14M|  1096   (5)| 00:00:14 |
|* 37 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLEG              |   290K|    13M|  1064   (2)| 00:00:13 |
|* 38 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_TABLEH           |     1 |     5 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 39 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | TABLEG              |     1 |    36 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 40 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN            | TABLEI              |     3 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 41 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TABLEG              |     1 |    36 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 42 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN           | TABLEI              |     3 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 43 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLEL              |     1 |    23 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How about using `EXPLAIN PLAN` to see what the planner thinks of the situation?

Comment: I've done it. To be fair, I don't understand all the output. But, why the query is always fast in IDEA (and SQL Developer too), while it's slow in code?

Comment: How about putting the definition of table (aliased as R) + the its indexes for starter?

Comment: Which table is `R`?

Comment: If you mean writing it at the beginning of the query, actually it's already the fist part of the JOIN written in the FROM clause.
R -> TABLEA

Comment: The `IS NULL` condition on a nullable field prevents Oracle from using an index on that field.  E.g., your slow query, without `IS NULL`, uses index `SYS_C0012290`.  Using an index isn't always a good thing, especially if Oracle underestimates the number of rows that will come out of the `INDEX ACCESS` plan step.

Comment: That's ok. But, why it's always fast in IDEA? And, called from code, it's slow? At code side there's just the DataSource, that wraps the connection, and the jdbcTemplate that runs it.

Comment: Are you _sure_ it is fast in IDEA?  Did you scroll to the end of the result set?  A query that uses an index that it would better not use will often return the first rows very quickly, but take much longer to return the entire result set.

Comment: Explain plans you have shown are incomplete. There is missing "predicate information" printed below the table (there is one row printed there for each asterisk * in the main plan )

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I was almost to say "yes, this is the problem!" but I've tried now. The query doesn't return enough data to reach the boundary set by IDEA (it's 500, actually I get 280 records). So, no, this is not the problem.

Comment: @krokodilko, I know. But I was a bit "scared" to publish how joins and other things are done here. It could be a "clue" for the structure of the tables (I'm a bit paranoic, it could be, but ... better than being naive).

Comment: You are looking for help in performance tuning, but you are willing to show us neither the query nor the predicate information part of the plan. It's guessing game. Anyway, how many rows does the query return ? The plans say there are either 7 or 2 rows in the resultset, is that true ?

Comment: Sorry, what I'm asking is why the query is fast in one context and slow in another, I'm not looking in performance tuning. The query is fast enough. But, if I would not have tried the extra conditions, would be unusable from the code. 
Anyway, no, the fast query returns 327 lines, while the slow 267.
About not showing the code, how could I show the structure of our tables?